# Can I store formatting of Range of cells into a variable in Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I know I can use ".copy" & ".PasteSpecial(xlPasteFormats)" methods to achieve my goal but I need to store Format for range of cells to use them multiple times later in my code.

Consider that each cell in my range has it's own format (Color,borders,...).

Comment: No, you cannot store formatting in a variable. You can store it in many different variables each corresponding to a single property of your formatting, which gets complicated quickly when conditional formatting is involved.

Comment: Practically agree with you; theoretically you can assign a mixture of styles & data via: ` x = rng.Value(11)`, on the other hand a big deal to analyze not only the xml <styles> section, but also where rows are identified in data rows by identical code and trying to find a way how to apply the whole thing back. @GSerg

Comment: What's stopping you from using `.Copy` and `.PasteSpecial(xlPasteFormats)`? Store the source cell in a Range variable and you can use it later?

Comment: @RaymondWu Actually in the end I did exactly as you said. Thanks.